# Conditional statement to pull out last names from a list

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I have a list of full names (titled "FullNames") and I am trying to pull out the last names. The problem is that some of the full names include middle names (e.g., some of the items in the list are "Craig Nelson" while others are "Craig T. Nelson") which stops me from using a simple list comprehension statement such as:

```
LastNames = ([x.split()[1] for x in FullNames])
```

Instead, I am trying to loop through the list with this code:

```
LastNames = []
for item in FullNames:
    if '.' in FullNames:
        LastNames.appened(item[2])
    else:
        LastNames.append(item[1])
print(LastNames)
```

However, I am just getting a bunch of letters back:

```
['u', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'a', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'h', 'a', 'i', 't', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'o', 'a', 'y', 'i', 'e', 'e', 'o', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'i', 'i', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'n', 'e', 'a', 'r']
```

Is there a simple way around this?

Comment: use 
        `LastNames = ([x.split()[-1] for x in FullNames])`

Comment: also you should write `if '.' in item:` instead of `if '.' in FullNames:`

Comment: since last name is always at the end of the name, so you need to get the last element after split for the last name, so `[x.split()[-1] for x in FullNames]` will give you last name

Comment: Thanks! One follow up if it's alright, sometimes there are items within the list such as "Craig T. Nelson, MBA" .... is there a way to quickly modify to pull the last name out of something like that, or would that require manual repair?

Comment: This approach doesn't support double barrelled last names at all - i.e "Craig revel horwood"

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_last(name):
    return name.split(' ')[-1].split('.')[-1]

full_names = ["Craig T. Nelson", "Craig Nelson"]
output = list(map(get_last, full_names))
print(output)

#['Nelson', 'Nelson']
```

Comment: Thanks! One follow up if it's alright, sometimes there are items within the list such as "Craig T. Nelson, MBA" .... is there a way to quickly modify to pull the last name out of something like that, or would that require manual repair?

Comment: @am.96 Yes, one option is to use `name.split(',')[0]` first and then do the rest

Comment: thank you @aminrd! this fixed everything.